# Python Class instance object has no attribute 'undefined_method'

Tags: python

##### Class definition

```py
class Car:
    
    amount_cars = 0
    
    def __init__(self, manufacturer, model, hp):
        self.manufacturer = manufacturer
        self.model = model
        self.hp = hp
        Car.amount_cars += 1
    
    def print_car_amount(self):
        print("Amount: {}".format(Car.amount_cars))
```

##### Creating instance

```py
myCar1 = Car("Tesla", "Model X", 525)
```

##### Printing instance

```py
myCar1.print_info()
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [37], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 myCar1.print_info()

AttributeError: 'Car' object has no attribute 'print_info
```

Need help in finding the error

Comment: You have no such `print_info` method defined in your class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is stated in the error message, tou have no method by the name `print_info`. Probably, you're trying to do:

```py
myCar1.print_car_amount()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Car:

amount_cars = 0

def __init__(self, manufacturer, model, hp):
    self.manufacturer = manufacturer
    self.model = model
    self.hp = hp
    Car.amount_cars += 1

def print_info(self): # Changed
    print("Amount: {}".format(Car.amount_cars))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. In particular, please make sure to address the question being asked when writing answers.